# Apache access to /www denied

Tags: apache, server, wamp

When I try to acces a site i'm hosting with WAMPserver 2.4.18 i get an error 403 : You don't have permission to access /www on this server.

I've been looking for some time now and I don't think mu httpd.conf is the problem.

my httpd.conf :

```
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.
# In particular, see
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "logs/access_log"
# with ServerRoot set to "/usr/local/apache2" will be interpreted by the
# server as "/usr/local/apache2/logs/access_log", whereas "/logs/access_log"
# will be interpreted as '/logs/access_log'.
#
# NOTE: Where filenames are specified, you must use forward slashes
# instead of backslashes (e.g., "c:/apache" instead of "c:\apache").
# If a drive letter is omitted, the drive on which httpd.exe is located
# will be used by default.  It is recommended that you always supply
# an explicit drive letter in absolute paths to avoid confusion.
ServerSignature On
ServerTokens Full

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to specify a local disk on the
# Mutex directive, if file-based mutexes are used.  If you wish to share the
# same ServerRoot for multiple httpd daemons, you will need to change at
# least PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "D:/Software/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.18"

Define APACHE24 Apache2.4

#
# Mutex: Allows you to set the mutex mechanism and mutex file directory
# for individual mutexes, or change the global defaults
#
# Uncomment and change the directory if mutexes are file-based and the default
# mutex file directory is not on a local disk or is not appropriate for some
# other reason.
#
# Mutex default:logs

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
start of loadmodule part
...
end of loadmodule part


#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#    
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin admin@example.com

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName <private - ip>:80

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#
HostnameLookups Off

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "D:/Software/wamp64/www/wordpress"
<Directory "D:/Software/wamp64/www/wordpress/">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
#Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride all

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#

#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require all granted

</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
#ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
ErrorLog "D:/Software/wamp64/logs/apache_error.log"
etc. etc. (i don't think the next part is the issue
```

I seem to have done everything multiple different sites/forums/video's instructed to do yet none of it fixed my issue

I have

- forwarded port 80
- added a firewall rule for port 80
- ... anything else?

Thanks in advance and please do not hesitate to ask further questions/edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you have a WAMPServer 3+ installed

In that case you need to edit the

```
\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
```

file and add your access control statements there.

As of WAMPServer 3, localhost has a Virtual Host defined for it, and that means that Apache ignores any access right changes in the `httpd.conf` file

If you have installed the WAMPServer 3.0.6 upgrade, there should now be a menu item that will open the editor on this file automatically

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Comment: I've checked both the wampmanager and the direct path but I couldn't find the file you are reffering to. I do in fact run wampserver 3, the 2.4.18 is my apache version (sorry)

Comment: Ok after some further searching i've found the file in wampmanager -> Apache -> extra -> httpd-vhosts.conf and it does work now! thanks

Comment: Can anyone give us some kind of pointer to the docs or whatever will explain to me/us  HOW TO "add your access control statements there" ? (Please & thank you!)

Comment: @ScottFraley You could start with the [WAMPServer forum, read all the **Sticky** Threads](http://forum.wampserver.com/list.php?2)

Comment: @fox125 Strange, I do not have an `extra` reference anywhere on the WampManager menus, are you sure about that comment